# Why is this caterpillar algorithm O(n^2) not O(n^3)?

Tags: algorithm

Can someone explain why this algorithm is `O(n^2)`? According to [this](https://codility.com/media/train/13-CaterpillarMethod.pdf), it's O(n^2). 
The reason why I think it's O(n^3) is because outer loop (for x) runs `n` times, inner loop (for y) runs `n-1` times, and in the **worst** scenario e.g. `A = [8, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107]`, the while loop (for z) will run `n-2` times hence overall `O(n^3)`.

For completeness, `A` is a sorted array with positive elements, a triplet (x, y, z) is a triangle if `A[x] + A[y] > A[z]`. Find how many triangles can be built from A.

```
        int TrianglesCount(int[] A)
        {
            int result = 0;
            for (int x = 0; x < A.Length; x++)
            {
                int z = x + 2;
                for (int y = x + 1; y < A.Length; y++)
                {
                    while (z < A.Length && A[x] + A[y] > A[z])
                        z++;
                    result += z - y - 1;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take a closer look at the below snippet

```
int z = x + 2;
for (int y = x + 1; y < A.Length; y++)
{
   while (z < A.Length && A[x] + A[y] > A[z])
      z++;
   result += z - y - 1;
}
```

The for loop is clearly executed `A.lenght - (x+1)` times, which is `O(n)`. However, the inner while loop is executed at most `A.length - (x+2)` times in total, because each such execution increments value of `z`, and it can be incremented at most `A.length - (x+2)` times until the while condition fails. Again, this is at most `O(n)`. Thus, the total time complexity of this snippet can be bounded by `O(n) + O(n) = O(n)`.

Since the snippet is run for every of `O(n)` values of `x`, the overall time complexity is `O(n^2)`.

A similar idea is used in [KMP algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm) for string matching.

Comment: I think I got you! The key is z increment is independent of y so though z is nested inside y it doesn't lead to quadratic complexity, rather it's O(n) + O(n) = O(n). Then with x iteration, it's overall quadratic. Best answer so far:)

Comment: Well, yes, mostly independently, this works because the array is sorted. So, if the inequality A[x] + A[y] > A[z] holds then the inequality A[x] + A[y+1] > A[K] also holds for K <= z, because A[y+1] >= A[y]. Thus we can start the loop for y+1 from z+1 rather than from the initial value of z which was x+2

Answer (score 2):

You should note that `z` is initialized inside x-loop, not y-loop. And on every x-iteration `z` could be incremented maximum `A.length - x - 2` times.

Answer (score 0):

The trick lies in the fact that `z` is increased `in total` up to A.Length:
E.g. if we get unlucky in the first iteration:

- x=0, y=1 and we get z to go from 2 to A.Length, in the subsequent y-loops, z won't be incremented at all.

Comment: z won't be incremental at all? z is reinitialised to x+2 in every iteration so it can still be incremented.

Comment: In subsequent y loops. It will still be incremented in the x-loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on explaining this.

First of all, you can't talk about complexity when n is small. The definition itself of complexity says that complexity only "means something" when n tends to infinity. For example, bubble sort on an array with 3 elements may seem like O(n).

With that taken out of the equation, here's about your algorithm:

Variable z is declared inside x-loop, not y-loop, therefore z will not be reinitialised every time y-loop is completed. What that means is that z will increase to A.length only once in each pass of x-loop. Once z reaches A.length, it won't increase any more and therefore it doesn't depend on the y-loop. I hope this explanation is adequate and that this problem is clearer to you now.